# Ant Design table row class name multiple conditions

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I have a table from the Ant Design component library which I have been applying a conditional class name. I'd like to add another condition but my syntax must be wrong. The first condition worked but after adding `(record.current_price === 'Timeout' && "red")` I'm met with a blank page.

Here's what I've tried below:

```
  <Table 
    columns={columns} 
    dataSource={context.products} 
    rowClassName={(record, index) => (record.current_price !== record.previous_price && "green") (record.current_price === 'Timeout' && "red")} 
    onChange={onChange} 
    pagination={{ pageSize: 100 }} 
  />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ternary operators will fix your issue.

So, the condition will be like:

```
rowClassName={(record) => (record.current_price !== record.previous_price ? "green" : (record.current_price === 'Timeout' ? "red" : null)}
```

Comment: But where do you define `record`?

Comment: rowClassName={(record) => (record.current_price !== record.previous_price ? "green" : (record.current_price === 'Timeout' ? "red" : null)}

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, best not to use nested ternary operator, like said in [eslint/no-nested-ternary](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary). So consider doing this:

```js
<Table 
  columns={columns} 
  dataSource={context.products} 
  rowClassName={(record, index) => {
    if (record.current_price !== record.previous_price) {
      return "green";
    }
    if (record.current_price === 'Timeout') {
      return "red";
    }
    return null;
  }
  onChange={onChange} 
  pagination={{ pageSize: 100 }} 
/>
```